# PHP array group by month and sum

Tags: php

I have an a php array as shown in this first image.

[image: Array before grouping and sum]

All I want is get the sum group the values by month as shown here.

[image: Array summed and grouped by month]

I know this might be very easy for most of us but to be honest I cant find a working way to implement it.

I tried searching on google but all results I find are about grouping and summing a database query result when for me what I have is an array in my hands.

Please show me correct function. Thank you.

Comment: the dates are all formatted yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Remove the day from the dates, and use that as the key in the result array. Then it should be easy to add the value to the corresponding element in the array.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Yes. All dates are yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: You can also use `strtotime()` and `date()` to convert a date like `2019-09-23` to `Sep 2019`.

Comment: `date('M Y', strtotime($date))`

Comment: Well @Barmar. Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to create a function from what you suggested. It's amazing you remind me to follow rules and still provide me with correct way to get answer. Thanks too much friend.

Comment: You can eliminate a lot of iterated function calls if you just group by the current date format, then after all of the grouping is done, you can format the keys ...if you need to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let's say that the first array with all the dates is called `$dates`:

```php
$datesGroup = array();
foreach($dates as $date=>$value) $datesGroup[date('M Y', strtotime($date))]=( $datesGroup[date('M Y', strtotime($date))] ?? 0 )+$value;
```

the algorithm is simple:
loop through the array, and than increment the right index produced by the date function

Comment: This code raises notices such as 'Undefined index: Sep 2019'. It should be checked if the index already exists.

Comment: you mean to do something like `$datesGroup[date('M Y', strtotime($date))]=($datesGroup[date('M Y', strtotime($date))] ?? 0) + $value;`?

Comment: Yes, or $group = date('M Y', strtotime($date));
  $datesGroup[$group] = ($datesGroup[$group] ?? 0) + $value;

Answer (score 2):

Okay I think this is exactly what you wanted.

```
$datewise_data = array
(
    '2019-09-13' => 3,
    '2019-09-14' => 1,
    '2019-08-21' => 2,
    '2019-08-03' => 1,
    '2019-10-10' => 3,
    '2019-10-15' => 3,
    '2020-02-15' => 3,
    '2020-01-14' => 4,
    '2020-02-17' => 7,
    '2020-01-03' => 2
);

$monthwise_data = array();

foreach($datewise_data as $key => $value){
    
    $month_key = date('Y-m', strtotime($key));
    
    if(array_key_exists($month_key, $monthwise_data)){

        // If we've already added this month to the new array, add the value
        $monthwise_data[$month_key] += $value;
    }
    else{

        // Otherwise create a new element with month as key and store the value
        $monthwise_data[$month_key] = $value;
    }
}
 

// Can also use ksort() function if needed here
ksort($monthwise_data); // ksort() function sorts an associative array in ascending order, according to the key

// Adjusting array as per your requirement
foreach($monthwise_data as $key => $value){
    $resultant_array[date('M Y', strtotime($key))] = $value;
}

print_r($resultant_array);

//Output
//Array ( [Aug 2019] => 3 [Sep 2019] => 4 [Oct 2019] => 6 [Jan 2020] => 6 [Feb 2020] => 10 )
```